# Symfony - Overloading an Entity set function with an id of another entity

Tags: php, symfony, entity, symfony4

Is it okay and feasible to overload a set function of an entity according to a field from another entity.

I have a field in table 1 (column E) which would consist of either column C or D (it's messed up to have 2 fields with the same field but it would be in another time, I just try to make this works).
The field E would depends on another table (2).

Example: If in table 2, fields "crit1" ou "crit2" are "localisation",in table 1, the column "tri_id" (column F) would take value of column D otherwise the value of column E.

example of structure of these tables

=> adapte_gaucher means "left-handed adapted"

[image: table example on Excel]

I was doing this in my entity:

```
/**
 * @param int $triId
 */
public function setTriId(int $shopId, int $triId): void
{
    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $products = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(Table1::class)
        ->find($shopId)
 
    if(Table1->crit1 != "localisation" || Table1->crit2 != "localisation" ) {
        $triId = $this->tri21 ;
}   else {
    $triId = $this->tri12 ;
}
    $this->triId = $triId;
    $entityManager->persist($triId);
    $entityManager->flush();
}
```

Would this would be an okay solution? I am too new to know if that's a good method or if I should never do that.
It's my internship project (I am just a junior and just get a year of programming behind me and without any framework course).
Sorry for the "pathos" lines but it would really help me to succeed it.

Thanks anyway.

Comment: It's better to move all that logic to controller and keep setter simple

Comment: Agreed I would avoid putting business logic inside an entity

Comment: The thing is the controller is called once only to return a json file and is never called.

Answer (score 0):

Though the idea of a "IF" is not judicious, I would like to just try a simple concatenation but:

```
public function setTri12()
{
    $this->tri12 = $shop_id . $pack_id . $adapte_gaucher_id;
    return $this;
}
```

or :

```
public function setTri12()
{
    $this->tri12 = $this->shop_id . $this->pack_id . $this->adapte_gaucher_id;
    return $this;
}
```

both return a null value as the 3 values are null.

Can I force it anyway?
Thanks